# How can I access a relation in entity framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Sorry for the title, but i had no idea on how to put the question.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Chat() {

        //get user first
        User user = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<User>("User");

        //get all connections entrys with user
        List<Connections> connList =  (from c in _context.Connections
                where (c.UserA_ == user || c.UserB_ == user)
                select c).ToList();

        List<User> userList = new List<User>();

        //now i only want to save the other users and not user
        foreach (Connections conn in connList) {

            //HERE IS THE ERROR
            if (conn.UserA_.Name == user.Name)
                userList.Add(conn.UserB_);
            else
                userList.Add(conn.UserA_);
        }

        return View(userList);
}
```

**Tables:**

```
User: ID, Name, PW  
Connections: ConnectionsID, UserA_ , UserB_
```

**The Problem:**

> conn.UserA is null.

**What i would like to do:**

I would like to get a list of all Users who are in a connection with user X, but honestly I have no idea what iam doing wrong here.

EDIT:

Example data:
User:
[image: https://puu.sh/zylnA/c2bf46a484.png]

Connections:
[image: https://puu.sh/zyltj/e8d450b084.png]

Comment: can you give some complete example data that cause a problem ?

Comment: You may use .include() for load related instances. Here is docs -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: that was it. Thank you @andrey.shedko